# Selected Values in Kendo Multiselect for AngularJS not getting updated. Model and View aren't in sync

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-angular-ui

Below is the view code:

```
<select kendo-multi-select="multiSelectControl"
id="multiSelectPortfolio"
k-ng-model="selectedItems"
k-value-primitive="false"
k-options="options"
k-on-change="dataChanged(kendoEvent)"
k-on-data-bound="dataBound(kendoEvent)"
k-ng-delay="selectedItems"
k-template="XXSPreventTemplate"
ng-blur="onBlur()"
></select>
```

Whenever I try to change "selectedItems" through the controller, two-way binding doesn't work. I can see updated array i.e "selectedItems" in controller but view never gets updated. Is there any way to force update the Kendo UI.

I was able to identify that controller gets updated array by the below code:

```
this.scope.$watch("selectedItems", (newvalue) => {
console.log(newvalue);
});
```